# Currently PayPal accounts in India are only able to send payments. This recipient is not eligible to receive funds

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, sandbox

I'm trying to payment from sandbox *buyer account* to *sandbox business*
   account.
**I got the error**

> Currently PayPal accounts in India are only able to send payments.
>   This recipient is not eligible to receivefunds.

This is my html form:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin /webscr" method="post">    
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="vpratap-facilitator@grepruby.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value= "5">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0" />
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and
       secure!"> 
  </form>
```

Comment: You are trying to get around their system, i.e. hack your way out of their terms and conditions? Very bad idea. There are tonnes of alternative payment platforms. Use one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

solution is create new account using Sandbox->Accounts->Create Account. Note the important part is **to use United States in country**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to this problem. For regulartory reasons PayPal is unable to offer full services (including receiving payments) in India at this time.

Comment: I know it's late, but your answer is wrong. Indians CAN very much RECEIVE payments from OUTSIDE India, just not within India.